# change li order - reverse the order

Tags: html, css

i have a "li" with 5 element order from 1 to 5. i set them inside a  fixed div as inline-block. when i ran the code the list order from 5 to 1 instead of 1-5.

the code:

```css
    #nav_bar{
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: white;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: -2px;}

    ul{
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
    }
    li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 10px; 
 color: gray;
 width: 100px;
 float: inherit;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I mean that the first item is located in the most left block (and I want him to be at the most right block), and the last item is located in the most left black (I want him to be at the most left block). The item should be write in Hebrew so i must keep on the right order. anyone know how to fix this without change the order in the html list?

tnx!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `direction:rtl;` [direction property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) on the list like:

```css
#nav_bar {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -2px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    direction:rtl;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: gray;
    width: 100px;
    float: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [Direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Will allow you that, use this `direction:rtl;`

```css
#nav_bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -2px;
  direction:rtl;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: gray;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```css
    #nav_bar{
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: white;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: -2px;}

    ul{
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
    }
    li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 10px; 
 color: gray;
 width: 100px;
 float: inherit;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="header">
  <div id="nav_bar">
   <ul dir="RTL">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider javascript and jQuery, there's a solution, as seen here : http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/12/jquery-reverse-order-of-ordered-list-child-elements.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = $('ul');
    var listItems = list.children('li');
    list.append(listItems.get().reverse());
});
```

This should work pretty well